# Ubuntu Files app missing internal icons

Tags: icons

wondering if someone has faced this issue, the icons in the Files and Software center are missing, i think these are system icons (search, details, etc..) unsure if something went wrong in some upgrade, does any one now how I can fix this

[Files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZJQ7.png)

[Software center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OvOw.png)

Answer (score 0):

I will answer myself, easy fix is to open system settings -> appearance and then comute between the themes, ambiance->adwait -> ambiance and now the icons appear ok, unsure if the issues only happens on startup.